# Python classes and subclasses

Tags: python, oop

I am trying to make a generic class for my vectors with operations and methods applying for both 2D and 3D. I have the following code :

```
class Vector:
    class _2D:
        def __init__(self, x, y):
            self.x = float(x)
            self.y = float(y)

        def addNormal(self, normal):
            self.normal = normal

        def __str__(self):
            return '<%s, %s>' % (self.x, self.y)

    class _3D:
        def __init__(self, x, y, z):
            self.x = float(x)
            self.y = float(y)
            self.z = float(z)

        def __str__(self):
            return '<%s, %s, %s>' % (self.x, self.y, self.z)
```

And I use my `__str__` method like this :

```
a = Vector._2D(1, 2)
print str(a) # <1.0, 2.0>
b = Vector._3D(1, 2, 3)
print str(b) # <1.0, 2.0, 3.0>
```

The fact is, I can't find (at the moment) a way to implement this so I could make it like :

```
class Vector:
    def __str__(self):
        try:
            return '<%s, %s, %s>' % (self.x, self.y, self.z)
        except AttributeError:
            return '<%s, %s>' % (self.x, self.y)

    class _2D:
        def __init__(self, x, y):
            self.x = float(x)
            self.y = float(y)

        def addNormal(self, normal):
            self.normal = normal

    class _3D:
        def __init__(self, x, y, z):
            self.x = float(x)
            self.y = float(y)
            self.z = float(z)
```

Which would be the proper way to do it I suppose, so the code is clearer, and less polluted with redundancy.
The "why" I am doing this might not seem obvious, but I just have lots of methods like `__add__` or `__sub__` that makes the operations on vectors easier. Especially as I am learning 3D.

I am widely open for suggestions as to how you would do it differently as I read that nested classes aren't that good in python, but I insist that the syntax 
remain slightly the same as if :

```
class _3D:
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x = float(x)
        self.y = float(y)
        self.z = float(z)

    def __str__(self):
        return '<%s, %s, %s>' % (self.x, self.y, self.z)

    def __add__(self, operand):
        return _3D(self.x + operand.x, self.y + operand.y, self.z + operand.z)

    a = _3D(1, 2, 3)
    b = _3D(4, 5, 6)
    print a + b # <5.0, 7.0, 9.0>
```

Comment: You realize that `_2D` and `_3D` won't get `Vector`'s methods, right? You are looking for inheritance, but instead you are using nested classes, which aren't used very often in Python.

Comment: My suggestion is only to avoid reinventing the wheel.  Numpy arrays make perfectly good vectors already.

Comment: Personally I would create a Vector2D class and a Vector3D class that would subclass your Vector2D. 2d functions could have the suffix XY at the end of their methods e.g. MagnitudeXY, AngleXY, etc. Doing as you suggest is everything but obvious to the user of your class.

Comment: `Vector3D` should *not* inherit from `Vector2D`, as a 3-D vector is not a special kind of 2-D vector. (The is-a relation does not hold). Both classes could inherit from a (possibly abstract) `Vector` class that does not make any assumptions about the dimensionality of the vector.

Comment: @chepner Honestly, having a separate class per dimension doesn't make sense to me.